# Count the number of trues in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following object:

```
  items = {
    1: true,
    2: false,
    3: true,
    4: true
  },
```

How would I count the number of trues? So a simple function that would return the number 3 in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `reduce` the object's `values`, coercing `true`s to `1` and adding them to the accumulator:

```js
const items = {
  1: true,
  2: false,
  3: true,
  4: true
};

console.log(
  Object.values(items).reduce((a, item) => a + item, 0)
);
```

That's assuming the object only contains `true`s and `false`s, otherwise you'll have to explicitly test for `true`:

```js
const items = {
  1: true,
  2: false,
  3: 'foobar',
  4: true
};

console.log(
  Object.values(items).reduce((a, item) => a + (item === true ? 1 : 0), 0)
);
```

Comment: Or `Object.values(items).filter(a=>a===true).length`.

Comment: @RobG I considered that too, but `reduce` doesn't require creating an intermediate array

Comment: Then `Object.values(items).reduce((a, item) => a += item===true, 0)`. Even simpler if truthy is sufficient: `Object.values(items).reduce((a, item) => a += !!item, 0)`. :-)

Comment: @RobG Oh, smart, coerce the boolean test rather than use the conditional operator!

Answer (score 4):

```js
const items = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: false,
  d: false,
  e: false
};

const count = Object.values(items).filter(item => item === true).length;

console.log(count);//1
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = {
    1: true,
    2: false,
    3: true,
    4: true
};

function countTrue4obj(obj) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && obj[p] === true) {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(countTrue4obj(items));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Rather than storing `true` and `false`, simply `add` or `delete`.

```js
const items = new Set();

items.add(1)
items.add(3)
items.add(4)

// 3
console.log(items.size)
```