# Find the length of object values which is not empty

Tags: javascript

I have an object, for example ,

```
let obj = {
  name: '',
  age: 16, 
  address: '', 
  city: '', 
  pin: 4564
}
```

I want the length of element which have a value rather than 0 or undefined  or ''.
my obj has 2 elements which have value( age and pin) soI want the length of obj as 2

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) + [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: also [Count the number of trues in a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846805/count-the-number-of-trues-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with `Boolean` on each element on it maybe

```js
let obj = {
  name: '',
  age: 16, 
  address: '', 
  city: '', 
  pin: 4564
}

console.log(Object.values(obj).filter(Boolean).length)
```

Comment: actually the `reduce` in the above [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846805/count-the-number-of-trues-in-a-javascript-object) is arguably a better 'one-liner' as it avoids creating an intermediary array.

Comment: @pilchard totally makes sense, great one  good to learn